# Parameter pass in PGSQL query

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to call an create function in my class which needs to carry a sql statement. I need to pass some parameters in that query and I don't know how to do it.

**The create function in roster_substitute class**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        rec_id=values['id']
        sub_day=values['roster_day']
        ros_time=values['time_slot']

   cr.execute("""UPDATE roster_days_allocation  SET roster_allocation_connection = (SELECT MAX(ra.id) FROM roster_allocation ra, roster_substitution rs
                            WHERE ra.emp_id=rs.sub_employee) 
                      WHERE allocation_start_day = **'sub_day'** AND roster_time_list = **ros_time**""")

return super(roster_substitution, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Comment: Just for info: with that query you're evading odoo's orm layer and all what comes with it, for example access right checks...

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me, but I didn't get what you are saying... could you just explain little bit more ???

Comment: When you use the orm layer by using the typical model methods like read, write, create, search, etc. odoo will check access rights/rules and constrains. Using directly executed queries will do nothing of that (except sql constrains of course). So use sql queries with caution and never if there is a possibility to inject some sql code from outside.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidelines. Thanks to you I have learn another new thing about Oodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using standard psycopg2 library then

```
cr.execute("""UPDATE roster_days_allocation SET roster_allocation_connection = (SELECT MAX(ra.id) FROM roster_allocation ra, roster_substitution rs
                            WHERE ra.emp_id=rs.sub_employee) 
              WHERE allocation_start_day = %s AND roster_time_list = %s""", (sub_day, ros_time))
```

See [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).